# jQuery load method: loading foreign domain?

Tags: jquery, load

Is it possible to load a foreign website into a `div` of my page with the jQuery load method?

```
$('#content').load('http://www.somedomain.com/server/whatever/file.php');
```

It's not working for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to work around the security restriction described by @Giorgi using a PHP-based proxy script.

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
 # Get the Referred URL
  $raw = file_get_contents( $_GET['url'] );
 # RegExp to Strip All Script tags and/or links with Javascript in them.
  $safe = preg_replace( '/<script[^>]*>.*<\/script>|[\"\']javascript:.*[\"\']/im' , '' , $raw );
  echo $safe;
} else {
  echo 'No URL Set';
}
```

Then use the jQuery load action to call pages like **proxy.php?url=http%3A//www.google.com/**

Not, the `preg_replace()` action is just a rough draft - you would want to do some major testing and tweaking to ensure that you prevent people from messing with your site this way.

Comment: what do you mean by messing with my site?

Comment: Cross-site Scripting - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting. Where javascript, within the third-party page you are calling, can be triggered as though it was from your site, potentially compromising security.

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) page:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 1):

You can't due to security restrictions in the browser.
Use a proxy.

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Giorgi says, cross site calls are often blocked due to security restrictions. However, if the remote site returns [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) the call will most likely work.

For other calls you have to call on a page on your own site. And that page could veru well be a proxy which fetches the requested url on the backend instead.

```
$('#content').load('/myproxy.handler?url=http://www.somedomain.com/server/whatever/file.php');
```

Comment: For security reasons (XSS for example) I don't think a generic proxy is a good solution. This might be a better solution:
/myproxy.handler?action=GetWhateverData and then the proxy handler knows the URL:

Comment: is it possible to use jquery load with a SUBDOMAIN of the same URL? if the load fires on http://www.mydomain.com can i load http://hello.mydomain.com/hello.php ???

Comment: It's possible, and it involves setting document.domain = "yourdomain.com". See http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/ for more information and sample.